# Objects are not rendering except when very close (almost intersecting with camera) in OpenGL

Tags: opengl, camera, clipping

I am trying to create a simple program that will display the Utah Teapot at the origin and view it with the camera, however the teapot does not render at all until the camera is extremely close (so that they almost coincide). At first, I thought I may have had the wrong polygon faces rendered, but when I changed it from CCW to CW, this problem was not corrected. I've added a function that moves the camera down the z axis in the -z direction each time z is pressed. Nothing is rendered until the camera is extremely close to the origin. The camera then passes through and the scene is not rendered again. I've tried with various lightings and camera positions and nothing helps. I no longer know what to change. Any help is appreciated. The problematic code is below.

```
#include <OpenGL/gl.h>
#include <OpenGL/glu.h>
#include <GLUT/glut.h>

void display(void);
void reshape(int x, int y);
void init(void);
void keyboard(unsigned char, int, int);


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DEPTH);
    glutInitWindowSize(800, 600);
    glutInitWindowPosition(0, 0);
    glutCreateWindow("Test");
    init();
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutReshapeFunc(reshape);
    glutKeyboardFunc(keyboard);
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}


void init(void)
{
    glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);
}

float camx = 0.0, camy = 0.0, camz = 5.0;

void display(void)
{
    glMatrixMode (GL_PROJECTION);

    glLoadIdentity();
    gluPerspective(30.0, 1.3, 0.1, 200.0);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluLookAt(camx, camy, camz, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();

    glFrontFace(GL_CCW);
    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glColor3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glutSolidTeapot(1.0);

    glFlush();
}


void reshape (int w, int h)
{
    glViewport(0, 0, (GLsizei) w, (GLsizei) h);
}

void keyboard(unsigned char key, int x, int y)
{
    if (key == 'z') {
        camz -= .3;
        glutPostRedisplay();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gluPerspective`, `gluLookAt` and `glLoadIdentity` all target the currently active matrix as specified by `glMatrixMode`, so this block of code is nonsensical.

```
glMatrixMode (GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
// ^^^ write an identity projection 
gluPerspective(30.0, 1.3, 0.1, 200.0);
// ^^^ overwrites identity with your desired projection matrix
glLoadIdentity();
// ^^^ overwrites identity your desired projection matrix with identity
gluLookAt(camx, camy, camz, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
// ^^^ overwrites your identity with a view transform that 
// shouldn't be in the projection matrix
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();
// ^^^ Loads identity into the modelview matrix
```

The end result is that your project matrix contains a view matrix and your view matrix is empty (identity).  Because you don't have a projection matrix, you're essentially defaulting to an orthographic projection of -1 to 1 in all three dimensions (otherwise known as normalized device coordinates).

Try this instead:

```
// Specify that you're targeting the projection matrix
glMatrixMode (GL_PROJECTION);
// set the projection 
gluPerspective(30.0, 1.3, 0.1, 200.0);

// specify that you're targeting the modelview matrix
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
// set the camera.
gluLookAt(camx, camy, camz, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
```

I'm fairly certain that `glLoadIdentity` isn't necessary at all because both `gluPerspective` and `gluLookAt` completely populate the active matrix.

Comment: I made those changes to the `display()` function, but now the entire screen is initially red (the color of the teapot), and as soon a I move then camera, the whole screen turns to black (the clear color). I am clearing the depth buffer and the color buffer, but it still is not functioning.

Comment: you also need to remove the other glLoadIdentity() that's in the middle of your draw code.  I would also switch to a wire-teapot until you've figured out the matrix stuff completely.

Comment: Thank you so much. This code finally works! I appreciate all of your help.